# django-summernote is not editable on Django admin page

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

Currently I am trying to implement `django-summernote` to my Django project.
I could `pip-install` it, set up the `urls.py`, `setting.py`, `admin.py` but it is not working properly on the admin page.

If I go to the page, the information is displayed but it is not editable.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here is the info about package versions.

```
Python 3.6.9
Django 2.1 
django-summernote 0.8.11.6
```

And here is a screenshot of the admin page:

[image: screenshot image]

The data is displayed but the none of buttons for html customization is displayed, and this is not editable. I can not modify any sentence.

I would really appreciate if somebody gave me any advice on this.

Details package info↓ (This is result of `pip list`)

```
----------------------- ---------
asgiref                  3.2.10   
beautifulsoup4           4.9.3    
bs4                      0.0.1    
cachetools               4.1.1    
certifi                  2019.6.16
chardet                  3.0.4    
cssselect2               0.3.0    
cycler                   0.10.0   
decorator                4.4.1    
Django                   2.1      
django-bootstrap4        1.1.1    
django-cleanup           4.0.0    
django-filter            2.4.0    
django-modelcluster      5.1      
django-pandas            0.6.1    
django-summernote        0.8.11.6 
django-taggit            1.3.0    
django-treebeard         4.3.1    
djangorestframework      3.12.1   
draftjs-exporter         2.1.7    
et-xmlfile               1.0.1    
google-api-core          1.22.2   
google-api-python-client 1.11.0   
google-auth              1.21.1   
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.4    
googleapis-common-protos 1.52.0   
gspread                  3.2.0    
html5lib                 1.1      
httplib2                 0.17.0   
idna                     2.8      
importlib-metadata       1.7.0    
jdcal                    1.4.1    
Jinja2                   2.10.1   
kiwisolver               1.2.0    
l18n                     2018.5   
lxml                     4.4.1    
MarkupSafe               1.1.1    
matplotlib               3.2.1    
mplfinance               0.12.3a3 
mysqlclient              1.3.10   
numpy                    1.17.2   
oandapyV20               0.6.3    
oauth2client             4.1.3    
oauthlib                 3.1.0    
openpyxl                 3.0.5    
pandas                   0.25.1   
pandas-datareader        0.8.1    
pdfminer.six             20181108 
Pillow                   6.1.0    
pip                      19.2.2   
protobuf                 3.13.0   
py                       1.8.1    
py-trello                0.17.1   
pyasn1                   0.4.8    
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8    
pycryptodome             3.9.0    
PyMySQL                  0.9.3    
pyparsing                2.4.7    
python-dateutil          2.8.0    
pytz                     2019.2   
reportlab                3.5.46   
requests                 2.22.0   
requests-oauthlib        1.2.0    
retry                    0.9.2    
rsa                      4.0      
selenium                 3.141.0  
setuptools               41.0.1   
six                      1.12.0   
sortedcontainers         2.1.0    
soupsieve                1.9.3    
sqlparse                 0.3.0    
svglib                   1.0.0    
tablib                   2.0.0    
tinycss2                 1.0.2    
Unidecode                1.1.1    
uritemplate              3.0.1    
urllib3                  1.25.5   
webencodings             0.5.1    
wheel                    0.33.4   
whitenoise               4.1.4    
Willow                   1.4      
xlrd                     1.2.0    
XlsxWriter               1.3.7    
xlwt                     1.3.0    
zipp                     3.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue with this command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You need to get the latest files from django-summernote to where you currently have your static folder. The same applies to django-ckeditor.